# How to use find('all') in Views - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, view, cakephp-2.0, findall

I searched a lot but I couldn't find on How to use the find('all') in Views as used in Rails, but here I'm getting the error "Undefined property: View::$Menu [APP\Lib\Cake\View\View.php, line 804]"
'Menu' is the model which I'm using to fetch data from the menus table.

I'm using the below code in views:

```
$this->set('test',$this->Menu->find('all'));
print_r($test);
```

Comment: retrieving date within view is violation of MVC rules. Please don't do this.

Comment: I know but to solve my problem, I know only this way, if there is any other way pls help.
I have to display all the menus in a table, I have a menu_id from another table, I need to convert the id to the menu name.

Comment: I think my post will solve your problem

Comment: Why can't you retrieve the data in the controller, like you're supposed to?

Comment: I'd reconsider a few times whether you really can't fetch the data in the controller action before resorting to fetching data in a view file. However, if you must, I'd suggest using reqeustAction ([Cake 2.0 API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/object#method-ObjectrequestAction), [Cookbook (1.3)](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/991/requestAction), couldn't find a book page on 2.0) **with** proper caching.

Answer (score 6):

Inside your Menu model create a method, something like getMenu(). In this method do your find() and get the results you want. Modify the results as you need and like to within the getMenu() method and return the data.

If you need that menu on every page in AppController::beforeFilter() or beforeRender() simply do

```
$this->set('menu', ClassRegistry::init('Menu')->getMenu());
```

If you do not need it everywhere you might go better with using [requestAction](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/object#method-ObjectrequestAction) getting the data using this method from the Menus controller that will call getMenu() from the model and return the data. Setting it where you need it would be still better, if you use requestAction you also want to cache it very likely.

Comment: Would you mind to flag the answer as correct if it works for you please?

Comment: @burzum:i voted that one up because of you giving right advice and suggest me

Answer (score 4):

***TRY TO NOT RETRIEVE DATA WITHIN VIEW FILE. VIOLATION OF MVC RULE***

try this in view file:

```
$menu = ClassRegistry::init('Menu');
pr($menu->find('all'));
```

Comment: without VIOLATION OF MVC RULE , How to do this functionallity?

Comment: Query in controller and then set to view. OR making query in AppController's beforeFilter function, store the result in a variable and then use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

In AppHelper ,

Make a below  function

```
function getMenu()
{

    App::import('Model', 'Menu');
    $this->Menu= &new Menu();
$test  = array();
$test = $this->Menu->find('all');
return $test;
}
```

Use above function in view like :

```
<?php

 $menu = $html->getMenu();
 print_r($menu);

 ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting the error again:
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in AppHelper.php.

I added the $this->loadmodel('Menu') in AppHelper.php, but I'm getting error that loadmodel is non-object.

Comment: I voted that one down because of you giving bad advice and suggest to violate MVC.

Comment: @chetanspeed511987 Thanks for your effort in replying me, its really helpful that I didn't know that AppHelper can do this much.

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp not allow this .

First create the reference(object) of your model using ClassRegistry::init('Model');
And then call find function from using object

`$obj = ClassRegistry::init('Menu');`
$test = $obj->find('all');  
echo ""; print_r($test);  `

This will work.